# Custom Value not saving in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I am making a module to insert a  custom fields to quote address.

My File

Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="impunkj_add_custom_field" type="Impunkj\Checkout\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Modulename/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="dropdown" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Also Layout Processor
Impunkj\Checkout\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout

```
<?php
namespace Impunkj\Checkout\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
    $customAttributeCode = 'dropdown';
    $customField = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            // customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'tooltip' => [
                'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
            ],
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
        'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'validation' => [
           'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true,
    ];
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Also in 
Checkout/view/frontend/require-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Impunkj_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

File 
Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['dropdown'] = shippingAddress.customAttributes['dropdown'];
            // pass execution to original action ('Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information')
            return originalAction();
        });
    };
});
```

Is there anything is missing 
Please if someone can help with this

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to add plugin for ShippingInformationManagement. Try following way:

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName::save_custom_data_in_quote" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Model;


class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extAttributes->getDropdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also need to add fields in database ?

Comment: Sorry but my concept is  not clear for checkout pages for magento 2.

Comment: Yes, you need to add column for that if you need that data in future

Comment: i add field in quote_address with column dropdown and add both of file in module but not saving when i checking in order from backend

Comment: You need to assign that too. You can't save when you pass data as extension attribute. So use aroundSaveAddressInformation plugin and save that data

Comment: If you can send me some sample step that is very helpful. Thanks

Comment: If you can guide me how to saved and show in admin in order. Thanks

Comment: This is looks like a module and large. Try step by step.

Comment: ok i saw your module on Git
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-checkoutadditionalfield
How to saved this in Database